# Почему я Анастасия?)

Tags: дефект, вконтакте

Нажал "вход через ВКонтакте", закинуло в какую-то левую учетку.
stackoverflow, что с тобой? где мой аккаунт?

Хозяйка, отзовись.

Comment: Я уже был Анастасией тоже, уже отписали разработчикам о баге)

Comment: Это все здорово, только где моя учетка?) и как на нее теперь попасть, если я регистрировался и привязывал только вк?

Comment: Ну видимо только ждать ответа от разработчиков, когда баг пофиксят. У меня просто на самом деле через ФБ был создан аккаун, а вход через ВК я случайно нажал и тоже попал в аккаунт Анастасии

Comment: Хреново. Ну, придется вопросы свои от этого аккаунта задавать. Может девушке будут лучше помогать))

Comment: Наверное, Анастасия удивится, когда зайдет в свой аккаунт, а у нее вопрос "Почему я Анастасия?"))

Comment: Пусть вот разрабы ей и ответят на этот вопрос)

Comment: Всё из-за новых оттенков серого, видимо.

Comment: ееее, я тоже Настя))

Comment: Начиная с первого вопроса только мужское склонение глаголов - "Возможно не совсем понял", "перенес" - так, что возможно  "Анастасии" здесь никогда и не было.